# Sonarqube SSO with crowd

Tags: crowd, sonarqube5.1, atlassian-crowd

This is about integration of Sonarqube with Atlassian Crowd(LDAP tool). I've integrated Sonarqube with Crowd and able to login through users created in crowd.

Now I'm not able to SSO (Single-Sign-On) Sonarqube with other Crowd applications using crowd.

I'm getting below error while starting Sonarqube service.

```
2015.07.07 00:22:20 INFO  web[c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Failed to find value for property: application.login.url

2015.07.07 00:22:20 INFO  web[c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Failed to find value for property: cookie.domain
```

The error remains same, even if we assign value of cookie.domain and application.login.url in sonar.properties file

.

Please let me know how to fix above errors.

Comment: what version of sonarqube are you using and also provide crowd versions, also any plugin that you are using with sonarQube for this activity. if possible update your question with crowd configuration that you are using.

Comment: Hi...Here are the details as per update,

Comment: Hi Here are the details I am using Sonarqube 5.1.I have integrated with Crowd 2.8.3.I am using Sonar-crowd plugin 2.0 for integration with crowd.

Comment: Hi Here are the details I am using Sonarqube 5.1.I have integrated with Crowd 2.8.3.I am using Sonar-crowd plugin 2.0 for integration with crowd...Here are the configuration of sonar ,sonar.security.realm=Crowd

# URL of the Crowd server.
crowd.url=http://ch2dlfx048.in.example.com:8095/crowd/

# Crowd application name.
# Default is 'sonar'.
crowd.application=sonar1

# application.login.url
application.login.url=http://ch2dlfx048.in.example.com:8095/sonar

# Crowd SSO domain
cookie.domain=example.com

# Crowd application password.
crowd.password=Password@121

Comment: Hi all ..Pls need your thoughts on the above issue posted...

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube Crowd plugin does not yet support Crowd SSO. See https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-crowd/issues/5

Comment: `The issue you are trying to view does not exist.` https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPLUGINS-694 appears to be out of date.

Comment: The SonarQube Crowd plugin moved to community support on Github; I updated the link!